# Disabling vertical scroll on ion-scroll inside ion-list when swiping

Tags: cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

I got a little problem when wrapping ion-scroll into ion-list.

This is my code :

```html
    <ion-content>

      <!-- The list directive is great, but be sure to also checkout the collection repeat directive when scrolling through large lists -->

      <ion-list show-delete="data.showDelete" show-reorder="data.showReorder">
 <ion-scroll style="height: 300px" >
        <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" 
                  item="item"
                  href="#/item/{{item.id}}" class="item-remove-animate">
          Item {{ item.id }}
          <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" 
                             ng-click="onItemDelete(item)">
          </ion-delete-button>
          <ion-option-button class="button-assertive"
                             ng-click="edit(item)">
            Edit
          </ion-option-button>
          <ion-option-button class="button-calm"
                             ng-click="share(item)">
            Share
          </ion-option-button>
          <ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon" on-reorder="moveItem(item, $fromIndex, $toIndex)"></ion-reorder-button>
        </ion-item>
</ions-scroll>
      </ion-list>

    </ion-content>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNyjGx

What i want is to prevent scrolling while swiping on ion-item, the default is working, but when i tried to wrap it, it is not working, can you anyone help me with some alternative?

The thing is i want to make the height of ion-list resizeable with css, so i'm using ion scroll inside ion-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simplified solution to the problem. Remove ion-scroll and give height to ion-content.

[CodePen Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJyKOB)

```
<ion-content style='height : 300px'>
```

Comment: You can also disable ion-scroll instead of removing it by adding `scroll="false"` to the ion-content tag: `<ion-content scroll="false">`.

Answer (score 2):

Use has-bouncing="false" in ion-content

```html
   <ion-content has-bouncing="false">

  <!-- The list directive is great, but be sure to also checkout the collection repeat directive when scrolling through large lists -->

  <ion-list show-delete="data.showDelete" show-reorder="data.showReorder">
      <ion-scroll style="height: 300px" >
    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" 
              item="item"
              href="#/item/{{item.id}}" class="item-remove-animate">
      Item {{ item.id }}
      <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" 
                         ng-click="onItemDelete(item)">
      </ion-delete-button>
      <ion-option-button class="button-assertive"
                         ng-click="edit(item)">
        Edit
      </ion-option-button>
      <ion-option-button class="button-calm"
                         ng-click="share(item)">
        Share
      </ion-option-button>
      <ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon" on-reorder="moveItem(item, $fromIndex, $toIndex)"></ion-reorder-button>
    </ion-item>
   </ions-scroll>
  </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
```

Comment: if U have side menu or something has-bouncing="false" will do